# Kronecker product and vec operator in fmincon

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have noticed that some MATLAB functions (which should be equivalent), within an objective function of `fmincon`, give different results.

Assume that you want to minimize `f=vec(y)'*V` where `y = x*x'` is an `n`-by-`n` matrix and `V` is an `n`-by-`1` vector, the calculation of `vec(y)` within the minimization function seems to produce different results whether you calculate it in two steps (see example below) or as `kron(x, x)`. Which one is the correct approach? I am using the default settings for `fmincon`.

--

Two steps calculation:

```
xx = x*x';
f = xx(:)'*V;
```

Comment: what are you trying to actually minimize? They are not equivalent functions

Comment: Well, if y is a `n`-by-`n` matrix, x is a `n`-by-`1` vector. `kron(x, x)` is equal to `vec(x*x')` by definition. Does it make a difference in fmincon?

Comment: I'm struggling to see how those two different procedures (i.e. `v1 = kron(x,x)` vs. `xx = x*x'; v2 = xx(:)`) ever could produce different results. I'm guessing the problem lies elsewhere?